# Read column as ranges to compare values

Tags: r

I have a column of values with ranges. How do I set R to read these as ranges to compare values and see if another column value is in that range?

```
> temp
  range1 number1
1   1:5      4
2  5:10     77
3  9:30     27
```

I'm having trouble inputting those values successfully into range().
Here is what I've tried:

```
> range(temp$range1[1])
Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘range’ not meaningful for factors
> as.numeric(temp$range1)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Not sure why as.numeric turns the column into 1 2 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we need to split the 'range1' ( if it is `factor` class, convert to `character` as `strsplit` needs input as `character` vector), loop through the `list` output from `strsplit` with `lapply/sapply`, convert the elements to `numeric`

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(temp$range1), ":"), as.numeric)
```

here, `range` is also not needed if the the `seq` is from 1st to 2nd element as we would be unnecessarily taking the `seq`uence and then get the `range`

---

If we are  comparing with the second column, one option after splitting at the `;` would be do comparison (`>`, `<`) to check if the 'number' lies in `between' the ranges or not)

```
tmp1 <- read.table(text  = as.character(temp$range1),sep=":", header = FALSE)

with(tmp1, temp$number1 > tmp1$V1 & temp$number < tmp1$V2)
```

---

With `tidyverse`, an option would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
temp %>%
     separate(range1, into = c('low', 'high'), sep=":", 
          convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>%
     mutate(flag = number1 > low & number1 < high)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping it would be as simple as inputting the original column values into the range for comparison, but I guess I have to go this route.